# How do I automatically grant all privileges to a schema created by a user in mysql?

Tags: mysql, permissions, users

Someone new joined the company and I created an account for her in mysql using the following:

```
CREATE USER 'username' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

She needs to create her own schema and so used:

```
GRANT CREATE ON *.* TO username;
```

The problem is that now she is able to create new schemas and tables but she cannot do anything with it. I'd like her not to have access to existing schemas/tables but be able to create her own db and do anything with it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

To grant all privs on database `mydb` to `username`

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO username;
```

To grant privs on a table `mydb.mytable` to `username`

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.mytable TO username;
```

I suggest you drop the user first to clear up any server-wide privileges.

```
DROP USER username;
CREATE USER username;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO username;
```

Why drop the user first? When you first create a user called `username` and login, username has no privs. Just run `SHOW GRANTS;` to see it. It should say something like `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO username`. At that moment, `username` can only login. That's your chance to create privileges.

If you run

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO username;
```

username will have global database privileges (all databases)

If you run

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO username;
```

username will have database-wide privileges on the `mydb` database only.

If you run

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.mytable TO username;
```

username will have table privileges on the mydb.mytable only.

You cannot mix them. If you do you accidently slip `username` privileges that `username` should not have.

If you want to see what privileges exist at the three levels run the the following queries

```
SELECT table_name,column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='mysql'
AND table_name IN ('user','db','tables_priv')
AND column_name LIKE '%\_priv'
ORDER BY table_name,column_name;
```

Here are privs for MySQL 5.5

```
mysql> SELECT table_name,column_name
    -> FROM information_schema.columns
    -> WHERE table_schema='mysql'
    -> AND table_name IN ('user','db','tables_priv')
    -> AND column_name LIKE '%\_priv'
    -> ORDER BY table_name,column_name;
+-------------+------------------------+
| table_name  | column_name            |
+-------------+------------------------+
| db          | Alter_priv             |
| db          | Alter_routine_priv     |
| db          | Create_priv            |
| db          | Create_routine_priv    |
| db          | Create_tmp_table_priv  |
| db          | Create_view_priv       |
| db          | Delete_priv            |
| db          | Drop_priv              |
| db          | Event_priv             |
| db          | Execute_priv           |
| db          | Grant_priv             |
| db          | Index_priv             |
| db          | Insert_priv            |
| db          | Lock_tables_priv       |
| db          | References_priv        |
| db          | Select_priv            |
| db          | Show_view_priv         |
| db          | Trigger_priv           |
| db          | Update_priv            |
| tables_priv | Column_priv            |
| tables_priv | Table_priv             |
| user        | Alter_priv             |
| user        | Alter_routine_priv     |
| user        | Create_priv            |
| user        | Create_routine_priv    |
| user        | Create_tablespace_priv |
| user        | Create_tmp_table_priv  |
| user        | Create_user_priv       |
| user        | Create_view_priv       |
| user        | Delete_priv            |
| user        | Drop_priv              |
| user        | Event_priv             |
| user        | Execute_priv           |
| user        | File_priv              |
| user        | Grant_priv             |
| user        | Index_priv             |
| user        | Insert_priv            |
| user        | Lock_tables_priv       |
| user        | Process_priv           |
| user        | References_priv        |
| user        | Reload_priv            |
| user        | Repl_client_priv       |
| user        | Repl_slave_priv        |
| user        | Select_priv            |
| user        | Show_db_priv           |
| user        | Show_view_priv         |
| user        | Shutdown_priv          |
| user        | Super_priv             |
| user        | Trigger_priv           |
| user        | Update_priv            |
+-------------+------------------------+
50 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Run the query to see the privs for 5.1 and 5.0

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that when user A creates a new schema/table, he has no privileges at all on the entities that he just created. I'd like him or her to have all privileges instead with no intervention from the root user (me). Is this possible?

Comment: so you have a user who has permissions in schema a. but is creating objects in schema b?  Or does your user only have permissions to a specific set of objects?

Comment: I'd like a user to be able to create schemas. Once a user create a schema I'd like him or her to have automatically all privileges on that schema. This way, I can let new users play around and be fairly autonomous without risking to compromise existing data

Comment: What you are asking is standard protocol for Oracle because when you create a user in Oracle, a schema is automatically generated in the default tablespace or the tablespace of your choice. MySQL does not follow that paradigm. In MySQL, a user with all privileges should be responsible for user creation and subsequent credential assignments.

Comment: A mysql user can use GRANT commands to assign privileges to other MySQL users, but can only assign as many privileges as the user owns.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLESPACE dwtblspc LOGGING DATAFILE 'D:\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata\XE\DWTBLSPC.DBF' SIZE 300M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1048K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;

CREATE USER prateek IDENTIFIED  by prateek DEFAULT TABLESPACE dwtblspc ACCOUNT UNLOCK;

GRANT unlimited tablespace to prateek ;

CREATE ROLE prateek_role;

GRANT CREATE SESSION,ALTER SESSION,CREATE TABLE,CREATE CLUSTER,CREATE SYNONYM,CREATE VIEW,CREATE SEQUENCE,
CREATE DATABASE LINK,CREATE PROCEDURE,CREATE TRIGGER,CREATE TYPE,CREATE OPERATOR,CREATE INDEXTYPE,BACKUP ANY TABLE,
SELECT ANY TABLE,CREATE ANY TABLE,CREATE ANY INDEX,ALTER ANY INDEX,ALTER ANY INDEXTYPE,DROP ANY INDEX,DROP ANY INDEXTYPE to prateek_role;

GRANT prateek_role to prateek ;
```

Hope it help.
Hope it help.

Comment: The OP's post was clearly tagged with MySQL - so your answer is not very useful ;-).

Comment: if you are conceptually clear then whatever the persistence doesn't matter so I think it can give a clear guide for anyone other than syntax.

Comment: This answer does not help because 1) there are no roles in MySQL, 2) many of the grants you have in your answer do not exist in the mysql grant tables, 3) there are no types in MySQL, 4) no sequences in MySQL, 5) no database links, 6) no operators, 7) no clusters, 8) no synonyms, 9) no backup grants, 10) There are separate GRANTs for 4 levels of access. They are not united in MySQL as your are showing from SQL Server, 11) Grants are not tablespace-dependent, 12) no concept of ANY TABLE and ANY INDEX as a separate grant, etc.

Comment: @Rolando I don't think this is SQL Server specific, it is Oracle specific. Doesn't change anything, just clarifying. :-) Anyway, it is an attempt to answer, it's just wrong.

Comment: @AaronBertrand OMG you're right, it is Oracle. it's in the path.